# Wrong Return Type

Tags: c#, return-type

I don't understand why I am getting an error of:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List
>   Notify.MainPage.webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object,
>   System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventArgs)' has the wrong return type

Code:

```
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += webClient_OpenReadCompleted;
```

And:

```
private List<SightingType> webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = null;
            var sightingT = new List<SightingType>();
            try
            {
                ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<SightingType>));
                ObservableCollection<SightingType> sightingTypes = ser.ReadObject(e.Result) as ObservableCollection<SightingType>;
                foreach (var sightingType in sightingTypes)
                {
                    sightingT.Add(sightingType);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            return sightingT;
        }
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: What are you returning your List<> to??

Comment: At the moment, nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The return type of an event handler should be void:

```
private void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
```

There's nothing at the other end to receive the return data.

Comment: How do I therefore get the collection of SightingTypes?

Comment: @AMR has the gist of it.

Answer (score 3):

This `webClient.OpenReadCompleted += webClient_OpenReadCompleted;` is just registering an event. It doesn't actually run that line of code when the event exicutes.

In other words

this

```
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += webClient_OpenReadCompleted;
```

is not equal to this

```
 var item = yourMethodCall();
```

If you want to retrieve the info from your completed event then you need to create a property or a global variable and assign it when the completed is finished

So instead maybe try

```
public List<SightingType> sightingT = new List<SightingType>();

private void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = null;

            try
            {
                ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<SightingType>));
                ObservableCollection<SightingType> sightingTypes = ser.ReadObject(e.Result) as ObservableCollection<SightingType>;
                foreach (var sightingType in sightingTypes)
                {
                    sightingT.Add(sightingType);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


 }
```

Comment: I've done something different. I'm firing a method passing over the collection of the SightingTypes. Now i'm getting a different type of error but I'll raise a different question for that I guess.

Answer (score 2):

`WebClient.OpenReadCompleted` is an event. Event handlers are delegates that must define a `void` return type. Your handler defines a return type of `List<SightingType>`. Therefore, your handler has the wrong return type.

Comment: Ok so in this case, how do I return the collection of SightingTypes?

Comment: @Subby - You'd have to show the surrounding code. Your handler isn't going to run right away so there's nowhere to return the collection to. Depending on what you want to use the collection for, there are different ways of coding it.

Comment: At the end of the OpenReadCompleted method I am calling a different method passing the collection. Would that be appropriate? All i'm basically doing is populating a DropDownList on the UI from the returned collection.

Answer (score 1):

The `OpenReadCompleted` event is an event of the delegate type `OpenReadCompletedEventHandler` which, according to its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.openreadcompletedeventhandler.aspx), returns a void:

```
public delegate void OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e
)
```

So you can't use a function that returns something else.

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers must return void. In your code, change:

```
private List webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
```

to

```
private void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
```

That ought to do the trick.